# The evaluation map $\phi_a : \mathbb{R}[x] \to \mathbb{R}$, such that $\phi_a(f) = f(a)$ for some fixed $a \in \mathbb{R}$, is a ring homomorphism.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

> The evaluation map $\phi_a : \mathbb{R}[x] \to \mathbb{R}$, such that
> $\phi_a(f) = f(a)$ for some fixed $a \in \mathbb{R}$, is a ring
> homomorphism. Therfore it's kernel is an ideal in $\mathbb{R}[x]$. All
> ideals in $\mathbb{R}[x]$ are principal ideals. Find the polynomial
> which generates this ideal.

SOL: $f(x) = (x-a)$ is the lowest degree non-zero polynomial which maps to $0$ hence it generates the entire ideal. Any polynomial in $\mathbb{R}[x]$ which vanishes at $a$ has a linear term in factor equal to $f(x)$.

I don't understand the question.

Q1. Generate what ideal? Find the polynomial that generates which ideal is it asking?
All

Q2. Why does it say that ideals in \mathbb{R}[x] are principal ideals?

Q3. In solution, why does $(x-a)$ generate the entire ideal? What is entire ideal? All ideals in $\mathbb{R}[x]?$

Answer (score 2):

Q1: kernels of ring homomorphisms are ideals. The question discusses $\ker(\phi_a)$. That is **this** ideal. I would rather state "find **a** polynomial which generates this ideal", since the polynomial is not unique, but they are all the same up to multiplication by some non-zero real.

Q2: I don't like the way the question is stated. I assume that the question is just giving out a fact, which can be assumed without proof (and which is actually true): Every ideal of $\mathbb{R}[x]$ is generated by some single polynomial (i.e., it is of the form $\langle p(x)\rangle=\left\{p(x)q(x):q(x)\in\mathbb{R}[x]\right\}$ for some polynomial $p(x)$).

Q3: I assume you have the solution at hand (which we don't). The polynomial $(x-a)$ indeed generated the ideal $\ker(\phi_a)$ (this is related to question Q1), that is, every polynomial in $\ker(\phi_a)$ is of the form $(x-a)q(x)$ for some polynomial $q(x)$, which is to say that $a$ is a root of any polynomial in $\ker(\phi_a)$ (is this obvious?).

Answer (score 2):

1. Recall that the kernel of a ring homomorphism $f\colon R \to S$ is an ideal in $R$. You are asked for the polynomial generating $\ker \phi_a$.
2. Univariate polynomial rings $k[x]$ are PIDs. They are Euclidean domains (you can carry out division with remainder), hence PIDs.
3. The claim is the ideal generated by $x-a$, which we denote $(x-a)$, equals $\ker \phi_a$. So there are two things to show: first that elements in $(x-a)$ map to zero under $\phi_a$, and second that all elements of $\ker \phi_a$ are of this form. That is what they mean when they say $(x-a)$ generates the entire ideal ($\ker \phi_a$). As for why this is the case: again, carry out division with remainder. Do you recall the factor theorem?